# Autoit code not working on chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, autoit

my File Upload(for firefox) code on .au3 file is:

```
ControlFocus("File Upload","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("File Upload","","Edit1","C:\Users\chaithu\Desktop\fileupload.html")
ControlClick("File Upload","","Button1")
```

for chrome the code is:

```
Sleep(1000)
ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
Sleep(2000)
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1","E:\Selenium Jar files\screenshots\March\testimgs\general-surgery-1.jpg")
Sleep(2000)
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
```

since dialog title changes from browser to browser I have created 2 files as above,but it is working only with firefox.On chrome,there is no error and no response while running the script directly or through selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

Your Chrome code works fine in the SciTE Editor. Maybe the cause is Selenium? Why not use the command-line?

```
Run("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe file:///E:/Selenium Jar files/screenshots/March/testimgs/general-surgery-1.jpg")
```

Seems to be a simpler solution.

Comment: would u elaborate the solution? I didn't get this...!

Comment: You're trying to open a certain local file with Chrome, aren't you? Your Chrome code works fine when I try it. A alternative solution is opening the file with the command-line.

Comment: it's working now after adding a chrome extension of AutoIT and switching off the anti-virus

Answer (score 0):

Put this part of your code in try catch block. It worked for me.

Like this:

```
try {
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("E:\\Script\\open.exe");
}
catch(Exception e) {
   System.out.println("exception is:" + e);
}
```